# Doxygen php with embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, php, doxygen, code-documentation

I use doxygen to document PHP-code and Javscript-code. That works great for plain language files, but not for main-web-php files containing embedded Javascript. Several options I have tried but none is working correctly. Have anyone a splendid idea?

Simplified example code:

```
<?php
$str = "How do I process embedded Javascript in doxygen";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
// These construct needs a php-file extension.
// This is just an example it is used within javascript functions also.
var str = <?php echo json_encode($str); ?>;

/**
Doxygen does not process this Javascript function.
*/
function hello() {
   echo "Hello world";
} 
</script>
```